# Why was there a man holding an Indian Flag during the insurrection at the US Capitol?

Tags: united-states, india, protests, washington-dc

Why was there [a man holding an Indian Flag during the insurrection](https://twitter.com/varungandhi80/status/1347060127845634053) at the US Capitol?

Is there any connection between Indians and Trump supporters?

Both India and the U.S are democratic counties.

Comment: Please provide the source.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire https://twitter.com/varungandhi80/status/1347060127845634053

Comment: Thanks. Note [several other country flags were waved](https://twitter.com/VincentPXavier/status/1347336887216852997?s=20).

Comment: Out of Topic but "Both India and the U.S are democratic counties." Technically, even DPRK, Pakistan and China are so-called 'Democratic' countries. It's not an absolute tag that can be proven by facts, but rather depends on the view of a person. e.g you may think India is pretty democratic but I can argue that it ranks bottom in allowing freedom of press/media so it is not democractic for me. It truly depends on your perspective....

Comment: An OK question, but keep in mind that the democracy counter-argument may not be a real contrast here, as a number of Trump supporters think they were upholding democracy by what they were doing, as deluded as that may sound. A more in-depth piece on that (with another example, not involving a flag):  https://gothamist.com/news/trump-fur-ever-costumed-capitol-rioter-son-brooklyn-supreme-court-judge Also the woman who died of a gunshot (Ashli Babbit) has profiled fairly extensively -- she apparently was a firm believer in (QAnon) conspiracy theories that democracy was undermined.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, [The Indian Express](https://indianexpress.com/article/world/india-flag-trump-rally-washington-7138784/) interviewed the man waving the flag, who appears to be a member of the Virginia Republican Party’s State Central Committee.

> The flag bearer was later identified as 54-year-old Virginia-based entrepreneur Vincent Xavier Palanthigal, who moved to the United States from Kochi in 1992. A member of the Virginia Republican Party’s State Central Committee, Vincent says that he had no intention of defaming the national flag.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> “It was because of my patriotic fervour and love that I took the Indian flag. Not to defame it or give it a bad name,” he told the indianexpress.com. Since the attack on the Capitol building, the image of the tricolour has stirred up a storm on social media, with hundreds of angry Indians questioning what the national flag was doing in the middle of the chaos.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> On Wednesday, Vincent, along with a group of 10 other Indian Americans, were participating in a Trump rally in Washington DC to protest against the Congress’ certification of President-elect Joe Biden’s win in the 2020 election. Carrying the flag was their way of representing the Indian American community, he claimed.

Comment: "Carrying the flag was their way of representing the Indian American community, he claimed." – One can only commend them on the fine job they did representing Mahatma Gandhi's ideals!

Comment: It just goes to show that just because you attend a protest (even if you wave a flag), it does not mean your views represent your “group”

Comment: The snarky side of me thinks it had more to do with the fact that his local flag vendors ran out of better alternatives. But, it takes all kinds and it isn't implausible that his statement is sincere and the whole truth.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This protester probably thought Gandhi would have supported him. That's cognitive dissonance for you.